# SHA1 library link not found using makefile

Tags: c, makefile, sha1

I'm having trouble linking the sha library with my makefile while compiling.

Here is my makefile:

```
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -pedantic 
LDFLAGS=-lssl -lcrypto
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
OBJS = dhtnode.o
PROG = dhtnode

.c.o:
gcc $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

dhtnode.o: dhtnode.c dhtpackettypes.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) dhtnode.c

clean:
/bin/rm -f *.o dhtnode
```

My function using the lcrypto library is here:

```
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdin.h>
//there are other includes but not concerning this part of the code

char sha() {
char *ibuf = malloc(sizeof(char));
ibuf ="172.0.0.1:11112";
char *obuf = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);

SHA1((unsigned char*)ibuf, strlen(ibuf), (unsigned char*)obuf);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    printf("%x" , (unsigned char)obuf[i]);
    }
printf("\n");

return *ibuf;
}
```

Here is the error I get when building with Eclipse:

```
C/p2p/dhtnode.c:107: undefined reference to `SHA1'
```

Can anybody tell my what is wrong with my makefile or possible eclipse settings?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling the object file, you don't need the `LDFLAGS`. You'll also need the `-c` compiler flag to produce an object file instead of linking a binary:

```
dhtnode.o: dhtnode.c dhtpackettypes.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c dhtnode.c
```

After making this change, the program compiles and links successfully for me.